# Speeding up the numerical integration of a certain function

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I'm using the following function

```
f[t_] := 
  3/4 t^-3 NIntegrate[(x^4*Csch[x/2]^2), {x, 0, t}, 
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
```

I have to apply large lists against it as well as use it in fitting routines like `NonLinearModelFit`. I can already significantly reduce the evaluation time by switching off the SymbolicProcessing option. Is there any other way to speed up the evaluation of `f` significantly?

A close to real-case example would be the following:

```
data = Table[250/t, {t, 0.1, 3000, 0.1}];
f /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming
```

For sure, the minimum and maximum argument of the function would be {0.001, 100000}.

//Edit

Sorry for the confusion about Min,Max arguments. The range can vary, but in the worst case Min,Max  of data is `{0.001, 100000}`. Therefore any simplification has to yield the correct result within that Range.

//Edit2

Symbolical Integration would be perfect, but due to the `PolyLog` functions, relative errors become very large, especially for `t>1000` and very small t. Also for me this is even more time consuming.

```
f[t_?NumericQ] :=  3 t^-3 NIntegrate[(x^4 Exp[x])/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 0, t}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
h[t_] = 3/4 t^-3 Integrate[x^4 Csch[x/2]^2, {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals && t > 0]
LogLogPlot[{Abs[h[x] - f[x]]/f[x], 10^-4}, {x, 0.001, 100000}, PlotRange -> Full]
LogLinearPlot[{Abs[h[x] - f[x]]/f[x], 10^-4}, {x, 0.001, 100000}]
data = Table[250/t, {t, 0.1, 3000, 0.1}];
f /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming
h /@ data; // AbsoluteTiming
```

I would like to have the relative error less than 10^-4.

Comment: You say "For sure, the minimum and maximum argument of the function would be `{0.001, 100000}`.", where I take "it" to refer to `f`.  But the arguments of `f` are taken from `data` and `Min[data] == data[[-1]] == 0.0833333`, while  `Max[data] == data[[1]] == 2500.`, Can you resolve the discrepancy for me.

Comment: You can symbolically integrate once and for all using `f[t_] = 3/4 t^-3 Integrate[x^4 Csch[x/2]^2, {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals && t > 0]`, which makes your numerical integration superfluous.